# Call C# button handler from OnClientClick function before another c# button click handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've such markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnGenerateReport" Text="Generate Report" OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" OnClientClick="javascript: return ShowConfirmBox(event, this)" />
```

In OnClientClick I fire event from another button by this code in JS:

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

and it fires.

But after js server handler doesn't firing. What's the trouble?

Comment: The code does what you asked it to do: execute the client-side click handler. Having one control try to raise another's events is rather bad practice. If you want to call the same code from multiple events, write a function and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click()`, it will acutually post the form and will invoke the `btnSave_Click` and process the same.

Here you cannot expect `btnGenerateReport_Click` invoke.

Inorder to do that you have to set some flag in and call the `btnGenerateReport_Click`

The below sample code may help you for this

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnInvokeGenerateReport" runat="server" value="0" />
```

and set it in JS

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdnInvokeGenerateReport.ClientID %>').value="1";

document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
```

In Code behind

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(hdnInvokeGenerateReport.Value=="1")
 {
   btnGenerateReport_Click(this, null);
 }
}
```